# How to use a transformed path in textPath?

Tags: svg

Consider following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="2000" height="2000" viewBox="-1000 -1000 2000 2000" 
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <style>text { font-size: 60px; }</style>
    <style>path { fill: none; stroke: black; }</style>
    <style>textPath { text-anchor: middle; }</style>

    <path d="M -258.8190, -965.9258 a 1000, 1000 0 0,1 517.6381, 0" id="ttO"/>
    <use xlink:href="#ttO" transform="scale(.85)" id="ttI"/>
</defs>

    <use xlink:href="#ttO"/>
    <text dy="55"><textPath xlink:href="#ttO" startOffset="50%">Hello</textPath></text>

    <use xlink:href="#ttI"/>
    <text dy="25"><textPath xlink:href="#ttI" startOffset="50%">World!</textPath></text>
</svg>
```

... and the resulting image:
[image: and the resulting image].

The explicitly defined path (ttO) and the textPath (Hello) using that path works fine. To define the smaller concentric arc (ttI), rather than calculating coordinates, I like to use transform. This works fine. However, I cannot use this second arc 'ttI' in the second textPath, at least Chrome doesn't render the second textPath. Is this because 'use' cannot be used to define new ids? What is the best way to do this?

If it was just this example, probably I can define one path halfway between two arcs and use that to draw textPaths with +/- offsets and draw the two arcs as transforms of the defied path. My goal is to extend the pattern I attempted to create more paths/textPaths at other angles / distances from the center with different languages to form a circular graphic. Without defining transformed paths, I have to explicitly specify at least one arc for each language.

Comment: It's because textPath's href has to point to a shape and use is not a shape element.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do it: I would create a text element using the same text path and I would scale the text - in this case `transform="scale(.7,.7)"`. Also since I want the text to be the same size as the unscaled one I would use a different font size: `1em` for the scaled text and `.7em` for the unscaled. Of coarse this is just an example. You can pick your font size making sure the font size for the scaled text is bigger than the font-size of the unscaled one by the same amount as the transformation.

Please observe that for the path I'm using `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`so that that stroke appears the same in both the scaled and unscaled one.

```css
svg{border:solid}
path{fill:none;stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-110 -110 220 220" >
 <g>
  <path id="path0" d="M90,0A90,90 0 0 1 -90,0A90,90 0 0 1 90,0" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"/> 
  <text font-size=".7em" >
      <textPath xlink:href="#path0" startOffset="75%" text-anchor="middle">Hello World!</textPath> 
  </text>
 </g>  
  
 <g transform="scale(.7,.7)">
  <text font-size="1em" >
      <textPath  xlink:href="#path0" startOffset="75%" text-anchor="middle">Hello World!</textPath> 
  </text>
  <use xlink:href="#path0"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid having the scaling factor everywhere because changing it means changing multiple places. `non-scaling-stroke` is helpful, thanks.

Comment: You can group the use and the text and scale the group `<g transform="scale(.7,.7)">` This way you'll have to scale only once

Comment: Say, the next few groups are scaled by 0.9, 0.8 etc. Then it is hard to come up with an original font size. Perhaps keeping the original font size 1em and using reciprocals of scale factor as the font size for the subsequent ones would work in this case.